# getJSON doesnt works in Wamp Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wamp, getjson

I am developing a web site in localhost with wamp.

I am trying to use $.getJSON in a customer register system to visit an api that only do inserts in database. The code is the following:

```
function user_register(){
    var name = $('.name-input').val();
    var id = $('.id-input').val();
    var phone = $('.phone-input').val();
    var email = $('.email-input').val();
    var address = $('.address-input').val();
    var password = $('.password-input').val();
    var repassword = $('.repassword-input').val();

    if(!name)
        alert('Por favor, ingrese su nombre.');
    else if(!id)
        alert('Por favor, ingrese su RIF o cédula.');
    else if(!phone)
        alert('Por favor, ingrese su número telefónico.');
    else if(password != repassword || !password || !repassword)
        alert('Las contraseñas suministradas no coinciden.');
    else{
        console.log("Hola");
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/clickpc.com.ve/web/api/userRegister.php?name="+name+"&id="+id+"&phone="+phone+"&email="+email+"&address="+address+"&password="+password, function(data){
            console.log("Chao");
            if(data.error == "false"){
                alert('¡Usted ha sido registrado exitosamente!.');
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

I selected all the variable from inputs elements with those selectors, everything is ok at this point. The if/else script Works fine to prevent empty inputs.

The issue is in the last "else". I can print "Hola" with console.log, but not "Chao". It were a test for $.getJSON.

Where is the problema? Its driving me crazy.

Regards.

Comment: What does the NETWORK tab within your WEB INSPECTOR say about this request

Comment: inserting data via GET, is a really bad idea. It is especially bad if you are passing password in plain text in a query string. I would strongly recommend using POST and using an https endpoint.

Comment: POST isn't more secure than GET.

Comment: Ok, i will change it but why getJSON doesnt work?

Comment: The inspect dont show any error.

Comment: Try doing a console.log(data) so you can see what you are getting back from the server. Or better still use the javascript debugger in your browser. Set a breakpoint on your console.log("Cheo") line and then inspect the data variable.